# HashMap different hashcodes return different values? Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap of two objects, but it seems to return different values because the hashcode is different.
Ex.

```
HashMap<HashMapTest, String> newMap = new HashMap<HashMapTest, String>();
    newMap.put(new HashMapTest("test"), "line");
    System.out.println(newMap.get(new HashMapTest("test")));
```

the hashcodes are different when I put it in the hashmap and when I get it from the hashmap. Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Let's see your `HashMapTest` class please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you provide your custom implementation of the `hashCode()` method in `HashMapTest`? I guess not, and that's the default behavior of `hashCode()` inherited from `java.lang.Object` (you are actually using two different objects.) Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) to provide correct `hashCode/equals` implementations for your classes.